# How do I check if dirty, but not when saving?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am using some code which I found on another post on here, it works well and when you try to close the page before saving your changes it prompts you and asks whether you want to stay on the page. The problem is that if click the save button (asp button with postback) it then gives you the same message.

So I basically need to stop it showing on the postback of the save button.

```
    var form_clean;

    // serialize clean form
    $(function () {
        form_clean = $("form").serialize();
    });

    // compare clean and dirty form before leaving
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        var form_dirty = $("form").serialize();
        if (form_clean != form_dirty) {
            return 'There is unsaved form data.';
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a flag to denote that you are doing a save and the rule shouldn't apply. Something like this:

```
var form_clean;
var checkDirty = true;

//this should be called when the save button is clicked, but prior to the page post
function onSave(){
    checkDirty = false;
}

window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if(checkDirty){
        var form_dirty = $("form").serialize();
        if (form_clean != form_dirty) {
            return 'There is unsaved form data.';
        }
    }
};
```

I would also recommend that you set the `form_clean` variable once the DOM is fully ready, that way you ensure that you are serializing the correct data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    form_clean = $("form").serialize(); 
});
```

The flag should automatically be reset after the postback once the page reloads

---

If you need help setting up the `onSave` function, you can use this:

```
$("#mySubmitButtonID").click(function(){
    onSave();
});
```

Comment: OK, it was because of the missing serialize clean form.

Comment: Now there is a problem where each time I try to leave the page I get the message come up even when I have not touched anything, do you know why?

Comment: @connersz; I would recommend setting `form_clean` in a DOM ready state... like `$(document).ready(function(){ form_clean = $("form").serialize(); });`